# Combine CSV in one with similar rows and different columns

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have multiple csv files which are generated from database queries

\n is for new line char in bellow text

received format-

**Month1.csv**

ID,User,Year,Month1, Month2,Month3,...,MonthN \n
2,User2,2012,12 \n
1,User1,2011,5 \n
4,User5,2014,56 \n
3,User4,2013,34 \n

**Month2.csv**
ID,User,Year,Month1, Month2,Month3,...,MonthN \n
1,User1,2011,10 \n
2,User2,2012,66 \n
3,User4,2013,40 \n
4,User5,2014,26 \n

**Month3.csv**
ID,User,Year,Month1, Month2,Month3,...,MonthN \n
4,User5,2014,67 \n
1,User1,2011,12 \n
3,User4,2013,23 \n
2,User2,2012,11 \n

Here col1,Col2 and Col3 is the same in each CSV but row sequence is not the same.

I have all these CSV's in one folderand required format csv in the same folder with different name with ID,User,Year,Month1, Month2,Month3,...,MonthN with data available in col1(ID),Col2(User) and Col3(Year)

I wanted to create specific format of CSV file as bellow -

Required format-
ID,User,Year,Month1, Month2,Month3,...,MonthN \n
1,User1,2011,5,10,12,...,50 \n
2,User2,2012,12,66,11,...,12 \n
3,User4,2013,34,40,23,...,13 \n
4,User5,2014,56,26,67,...,52 \n

I wanted the solution in VBS so we can execute it on any of the windows machine without any extra software. Can anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Use the filesystems object to open each CSV and iterate through them ignoring the 1st line.

you can then use split using "," as you delimiter.

if you require to compare the 1st 3 fields and only output unique items then you can use a dictionary object. once your sting is split add all 3 fields to one string check to see if its in your dictionary object if not write it out and add to dictionary. If it is ignore and carry on.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Copy the first CSV to the desired new file name. Read the content from each other CSV and split it at `vbLf`. Skip the first field of the array (which contains the headers) and append the rest to the destination CSV. Somewhat like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

isFirst = True
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\folder").Files
  If isFirst Then
    f.Copy "AllMonths.csv"
    isFirst = False
  Else
    Set csv = fso.OpenTextFile("AllMonths.csv", 8)
    lines = Split(f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll, vbLf)
    For i = 1 To UBound(lines)
      csv.Write lines(i) & vbLf
    Next
    csv.Close
  End If
Next
```